# DevExpress BlazorServer DataGrid LayoutChanged Event doesn't fire after refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, devexpress, blazor, blazor-server-side

**the problem:**
when a user refreshes the page and then changes the layout of the data-grid there's no `LayoutChanged` event. Before a refresh the event fires just fine.

**the suspect:**
in my razor component is a if-condition around the whole html which checks if the base-component is initialized because the `LayoutRestoring` event fires when the grid initializes but i need some data the base-component handles. When I remove the if-condition the `LayoutChanged` event fires just fine even after a refresh.

**why I do it that way:**
balzor renders a component before doing the first `await` in the OnInitializedAsync method and after the OnInitializedAsync method is finished. When the data-grid is initialized the `LayoutRestoring` event is fired but for loading the right layout I need some information that the base-component handles. I can't move the functionality from the base-component into my component and the user should not press a button to save the current layout.

Comment: There's a few misconceptions around the component lifecycle cycle and rendering. There's only one set-in-stone call to `StateHasChanged`.  This occurs at the completion of `SetParametersAsync` - the end of the synchronous part of the component refresh cycle.  There are two other conditional calls to `StateHasChanged`.  One is in initialization, and runs only when `OnInitializedAsync` yields but isn't complete.  The second is in parameter set and runs only if `OnParametersSetAsync` yields but isn't complete.  It's clearly stated in the Microsoft diagram.

Comment: The diagram https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle/_static/lifecycle1.png?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: I found the solution. This was a bug in the code from DevExpress. https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/versionhistory

Comment: Good, you need to close off this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the code from DevExpress. supportcenter.devexpress.com/versionhistory